# Same condition on date True with Series but False using element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, series

Why is the same condition True with a Series but False using the same element of the Series directly?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime('2013-11')},
     index=[0])
print(df['date'] == '2013-11')
print('')
print(df.loc[0,'date'] == '2013-11')
```

I obtain:

```
0    True
Name: date, dtype: bool

False
```

Comment: Try printing the value for `print(df.loc[0,'date'])`. What you get?

Comment: Pandas will convert the string to the right side of the comparison to a datetime object, but it doesn't try to convert a string to an integer or float if the left side is a number? That, to me, is truly weird.

Answer (score 2):

Because:

1. `df['date']` is a `pandas.Series` of `dtype` `datatime64[ns]`
2. `df['date'] == '2013-11'` is a call to `pandas.Series.__eq__` and Pandas can do whatever it wants when it writes that method.

What Pandas does is supposed to help you by realizing that you are comparing a string to a `series` of `dtype` `datetime`.  So it attempts to parse the string as something useful and then does the comparison.  This is part of the value add Pandas provides.

Comment: I am not sure that's a great "value add". It seems to me like a fairly opinionated way to handle equality.

Comment: The behavior is definitely confusing, +1 for adding some sense to it

Comment: Does anyone know the corresponding part in the source code that performs this kind of conversion? Would be nice to see what's really going on under the hood, especially since [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html#pandas.Series.eq) doesn't say a word about that; actually it even indicates the opposite: *"Equal to of series and other, element-wise (binary operator eq)."*.

Comment: @a_guest I just created [a gist here](https://gist.github.com/AbdouSeck/24995e9ad701a454fd84b5388e20c3e0) that explains where in the source code the coercion occurs. In my opinion, this is not a good feature.

Comment: @Abdou Great, thanks. I suggest opening an issue at the github repo. Either the documentation needs to be updated or this behavior needs to be changed (for consistency among data types).

Comment: @a_guest, [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23234) is the issue if interested.